# C vs C++ why is this macro not expanded to a constant?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, c-preprocessor

I am using gcc/g++. The below code compiles fine with `gcc -S test.c`, however with `g++ -S test.cpp` I get `error: requested alignment is not an integer constant`. If I look at the preprocessor output for both it looks identical. So my question is why isn't `ALIGN_BYTES` being evaluated to the constant 64 by the preprocessor in the C++ case? (If I replace `ALIGN_BYTES` with the constant 64 it works fine)

```
/* test.c, test.cpp */
#define BITS 512
#define ALIGN_BYTES (BITS / 8)

#define ALIGN __attribute__ ((aligned(ALIGN_BYTES)))

typedef char* ALIGN char_PT;
```

Comment: `__attribute__` is a gcc extension, so look there. C11 has [`_Alignas`](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas), C++11 [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas).

Comment: Deleted previous comment, `#define ALIGN alignas(ALIGN_BYTES)`  does in fact fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a macro expansion issue. The macro is not expanded to a constant in either C or C++, here. The preprocessor does not do arithmetic, so it simply generates the expression `512 / 8` which isn't a constant, but which the compiler should definitely be able to reduce to one.

The preprocessor generates the same code for C and C++ here, but GCC (for reasons I do not understand) treats the `__attribute__` extension differently in the two languages. I really have no idea why, there likely are good reasons, but someone else will have to explain that.

If you compile C, `gcc` is happy with `aligned((512 / 8))`, but if you compile C++ with `g++` it will complain that `512 / 8` is not a constant. It is right, I guess, but really also wrong.

There are other cases where it is the opposite, where `g++` is happy with a non-constant, but `gcc` is not. If you declare a `static const int` for example, you can use it in `__attribute__((aligned(...))` in C++ but not in C. Again, I cannot explain why. It's a compiler extension and GCC can do whatever. And for some reason, it will treat the two languages differently here.

```c
/* g++ will complain about this one; gcc will not */
typedef char *__attribute__((aligned((512 / 8)))) char_PT;

/* gcc will complain about this one; g++ will not */
static const int A = 16;
typedef char *__attribute__((aligned(A))) char_PT2;
```

I suppose, though, that since we know one version that works with C and another that works with C++, we could do this:

```c
#define BITS 512

#ifdef __cplusplus
static const unsigned int ALIGN_BYTES = BITS / 8;
#define ALIGN __attribute__((aligned(ALIGN_BYTES)))
#else /* C */
#define ALIGN_BYTES (BITS / 8)
#define ALIGN __attribute__((aligned(ALIGN_BYTES)))
#endif

typedef char *ALIGN char_PT;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Deduplicator suggested, `__attribute__` is a gcc extension. Using the below fixed the problem.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define ALIGN alignas(ALIGN_BYTES)
#else
#define ALIGN __attribute__ ((aligned(ALIGN_BYTES)))
#endif
```

Comment: For c use `_Alignas`

Comment: @tstanisl [_Alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) says it cannot be used in a `typedef`